# ActiveRecord self-join has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, associations

I have a model `User` and I need to create a self-referential association, lets call it `friends`, where if `user1` is in `user2`'s `friends` collection, then `user2`, is also in `user1`'s `friends` collection.

My understanding was that I would need a join table to accomplish this, however ActiveRecord is not letting me create a join table where both columns have the same name. I was trying to see if I could customize the column names, like `user1_id`, `user2_id`, but I can't seem to find an option that will let me do it.

Note that I am using UUIDs for all primary keys, and my database is PostgreSQL.

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.name :string
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :users, column_options: { type: :uuid } do |t|
      t.timestamps

      t.index :user_id
      t.index :created_at
      t.index :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

And of course I get:

```
ArgumentError: you can't define an already defined column 'user_id'.
```

I want to be able to do `user1.friends << user2`, etc., which would result in `user1.friends` containing `user2` and `user2.friends` containing `user1`

Is there a way I can make this work?

EDIT: I got it working using the following, however the sets seem to be one way e.g. `user1.friends << user2` does not mean that `user2.friends` will contain `user1`

```rb
class CreateUsersFriends < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :friends, column_options: { type: :uuid } do |t|
      t.timestamps

      t.index :created_at
      t.index :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:friends,
    join_table: :users_friends,
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    association_foreign_key: :friend_id,
    order: {created_at: :asc},
    class_name: :User
  )
end
```

Comment: hi there, how exactly are you adding friends to your user?

Comment: `user1.friends << user2`

Comment: thx for the quick response

Comment: if you want to use user.friends then you need to rename the relation on your user model, could you try user1.users << user2?

Comment: let me know if that worked for you @Sam Johnson 

Comment: Same problem -- `user1.users << user2`, `user1.users` will have `user2` in it, but even after reloading `user2`, `user2.users` is still empty

Comment: but that is not the same problem @Sam Johnson right? the issue you mentioned above was an error, what you want then is a bidirectional approach that is different from what I mentioned in my answer, and what I understand from the question

Comment: "I have a model User and I need to create a self-referential association, lets call it friends, where if user1 is in user2's friends collection, then user2, is also in user1's friends collection." It could be that a different association type is needed.

Comment: mm didn't noticed that part on my first read, will edit the answer so you can use the bidirectional approach 

Comment: thanks, having googled further it looks like the unidirectional approach is actually harder so we should probably keep both as there isn't a good question anywhere that has the unidirectional solution

Comment: yup as you mentioned the bidirectional approach can be trickier and there is not too much info about it, the best approach as far as I know is the one I posted on my answer, hope this helps @Sam Johnson

Comment: In case it works for you pls remover the comment from the answer, so the people can use it without think there is an error on the code thx in advance

Comment: Note for others: the method used above works if you want bidirectional, the method used below in the accepted solution works if you want unidirectional

Comment: Happy to know that worked for you @Sam Johnson 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is a unidirectional **has_many** association so you should be able to do it as follow:

```rb
class CreateUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table 'user_friends', :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "user_a_id", :null => false
      t.integer "user_b_id", :null => false
    end
  end
end
```

And then in your user model:

```rb
has_and_belongs_to_many(:users,
    :join_table => "user_friends",
    :foreign_key => "user_a_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "user_b_id")
```

If you want to do something like `user1.friends << user2`, then you need to edit the code above to:

```rb
has_and_belongs_to_many(:friends,
    :join_table => "user_friends",
    :foreign_key => "user_a_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "user_b_id")
```

As mentioned above in the comments the bidirectional approach can be tricky to maintain and simulate, a way to accomplish this is using the [has_many through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). With that said if what you need is a bidirectional approach then you can do something like the below:

So within your user model:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :lover_loves, foreign_key: :love_id, class_name: "Love" 

  has_many :lovers, through: :lover_loves, source: :lover


  has_many :loves_lover, foreign_key: :lover_id, class_name: "Love"    
   
  has_many :loves, through: :loves_lover, source: :love
end
```

```rb
class Love < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lover, foreign_key: "lover_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :love, foreign_key: "love_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

So for the sake of the example and the naming, I changed to use a **love** association which can be more 'transitive', and easy to understand (you will need to use it as separate associations).

Here is a small snippet to use it:

```rb
user1.lovers << user2

user2.loves # should contain user1
```

Hope this helps!